# Clean Liferay installation for portlet development?

Tags: eclipse, liferay, portlet

Suppose that I have to develop a simple Liferay portlet. Is it possible to prepare some cleaned installation, which contains only very basic things? I have erased many of the webapp folders but have Liferay loading for 73 seconds. What more can be disabled?

Comment: http://docs.liferay.com/portal/4.3/official/liferay-portlet-development-guide-4.3.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete everything less than the ROOT folder under webapps. 
To speedup you can also use in memory database and disable some spring service. 
Please find following configuration files for db and spring services that I use for testing.

```
#In memory database for testing purpose.  
jdbc.default.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:lportal
jdbc.default.username=sa
jdbc.default.password=

ehcache.portal.cache.manager.jmx.enabled=false

value.object.listener.com.liferay.portal.model.LayoutSet=

# Disable the scheduler for Unit testing
scheduler.enabled=false

hibernate.configs=\
        META-INF/mail-hbm.xml,\
        META-INF/portal-hbm.xml,\
        META-INF/ext-hbm.xml

# Comment or uncomment spring configuration files below as needed.  
spring.configs=\
        META-INF/base-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/infrastructure-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/management-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/util-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/jpa-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/audit-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/cluster-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/editor-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/jcr-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/ldap-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/messaging-core-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/messaging-misc-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/poller-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/rules-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/scheduler-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/scripting-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/search-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/workflow-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/counter-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/document-library-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/mail-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/portal-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/portlet-container-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/dynamic-data-source-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/shard-data-source-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/memcached-spring.xml,\
#        META-INF/monitoring-spring.xml,\
        META-INF/ext-spring.xml
```

Comment: Note to self: The name of this config file is probably something like: tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties (I tend to forget this after a while not working with liferay)

Comment: The file is called portal-test.properties, as can be read here: http://agile-reflections.opnworks.com/2010/06/portlet-unit-testing-with-liferay-6.html

Answer (score 1):

How much memory do you have in your computer? What memory settings do you have for Liferay? If the computer is using any swap space during startup, more main memory (or less apps in memory) will help most.

And, probably more important: What's the reason for you to optimize load time? Typically you rarely start/restart the server, unless you're constantly redeploying your ext-plugins.

If you're using the Liferay Development Tools (Liferay IDE or Liferay Developer Studio) you'll be able to deploy into the running system automatically. The Plugin SDK does the same thing from ant.

Comment: I have 12 Gb. I am using Liferay IDE but it requires restart on some changes.